# Google reCaptcha Enterprise NugGet Package Installation Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to add reCaptcha Enterprise NuGet package "Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1" for .net framework 4.5 but facing below issue. I tried to change the framework version and NuGet package version but no luck. Can anyone please suggest how it can be fixed. I found limited supporting material for reCaptcha Enterprise all where mostly are reCaptcha V3.

> Could not install package 'Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1 1.4.0'.
> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1',  but the package does not contain any
> assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
> framework.  For more information, contact the package author.*

[image]

Comment: As the error messages suggests, your framework version is not supported. You can check the required versions [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1/#dependencies-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the same error message is saying, Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1 is not compatible with .NET Framework 4.5. The following link has the compatible Google.Cloud.RecapltchaEnterprise’s version and release for .NET Framework 4.5 [Release 1.55.0.2437](https://libraries.io/nuget/Google.Apis.RecaptchaEnterprise.v1):

In case it doesn’t work, that’s the task, look for the compatible release.

Comment: Thanks @Nestor Daniel Ortega for pointing out this. I added reference "Google.Apis.RecaptchaEnterprise.v1" which supports .Net Framework version 4.5. But I am unable to get Create Assessment C# code snippet for Google.Apis.RecaptchaEnterprise.v1 reference API.

[https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment#c]Code snippet available on documentation is only for latest API. Any help in this regard